# Laravel: MYSQL query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a working query goes like this

```
SELECT s.name as status, q.name as quality, p.name process, count(*) 
FROM plates 
     JOIN equipment_status_codes s on equipment_status_code_id = s.id 
     JOIN plate_qualities q on plate_quality_id = q.id 
     JOIN processes p on process_id = p.id WHERE project_id in 
          (SELECT id 
           from projects 
           WHERE name like 'SPIRIT') 
GROUP BY s.name, q.name, p.name ASC with ROLLUP
```

This works just and returns results just fine.

Now I am trying to put this in laravel syntax, but having some difficulties.

So I was thinking something along these lines.

```
  return Plate::select('equipment_status_codes.name as Status', 'plate_qualities.name as Quality', 'processes.name as Process')
    ->join('equipment_status_codes', 'plates.equipment_status_code_id', '=', 'equipment_status_codes.id')
    ->join('plate_qualities', 'plates.plate_quality_id', '=', 'plate_qualities.id')
    ->join('processes', 'plates.process_id', '=', 'processes.id')

    ->groupBy(DB::raw('equipment_status_code_id WITH ROLLUP'))
     ...
    ...
    ->get();
```

Would someone help out. Thanks in advance!

Update: 
@Govind Samrow

I have tried this query. It works (with couple of small adjustment) But I am not getting the same results as the one I get when I run the sql query.

I included screen shots.

So when I run the sql query.

I get the following results.

[image]

When I run the laravel query.

```
  return  DB::table('plates')
    ->join('equipment_status_codes', 'equipment_status_code_id', '=', 'equipment_status_codes.id')
    ->join('plate_qualities', 'plate_quality_id', '=', 'plate_qualities.id')
    ->join('processes', 'process_id', '=', 'processes.id')

    ->whereRaw("project_id IN(SELECT id from projects WHERE name like 'SPIRIT')")
    ->select(DB::raw('equipment_status_codes.name as Status'), DB::raw('IFNULL(plate_qualities.name, NULL) as Quality'), DB::raw('IFNULL(processes.name, NULL) as process'), DB::raw("COUNT(*) as Total" ))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('equipment_status_codes.name WITH ROLLUP', 'plate_qualities.name WITH ROLLUP', 'processes.name WITH ROLLUP', 'asc'))
    ->get();
```

I get the following.

[image]

Almost there, but I am not sure what's going on?! Any ideas?

Comment: while you use surely eloquent you shouldn't use entity instead of query ?

Comment: @MacBooc if you have any suggestions please share those. I am open to other solutions as well.

Comment: actually i don't really use Laravel but check out the documentation of eloquent, your query will be really simple to write https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

Comment: @MacBooc if you're just going to post a link to the documentation, at least don't link to one that's more than two years older than the most current one.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @JoelHinz that was the first link when you type "eloquent php" on google, then i'm sorry if it's not the most up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `whereRaw` for sub query in where clause Try this:

```
DB::table('plates')
    ->join('equipment_status_codes', 'equipment_status_code_id', '=', 'equipment_status_codes.id')
    ->join('plate_qualities', 'plate_quality_id', '=', 'plate_qualities.id')
    ->join('processes', 'process_id', '=', 'processes.id')
    ->whereRaw("project_id IN(SELECT id from projects WHERE name like 'SPIRIT')")
    ->select('equipment_status_codes.name as status', 'plate_qualities.name as quality', 'q.name as quality', 'processes.name as Process', DB::raw("COUNT(*) as Total"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('equipment_status_codes.name, plate_qualities.name, processes.name ASC with ROLLUP'))->get();
```

Here is raw sql result of above that got with `toSql()`:

```
select `equipment_status_codes`.`name` as `status`, `plate_qualities`.`name` as `quality`, `q`.`name` as `quality`,
 `processes`.`name` as `Process`, COUNT(*) as Total from `plates` 
 inner join `equipment_status_codes` on `equipment_status_code_id` = `equipment_status_codes`.`id` 
 inner join `plate_qualities` on `plate_quality_id` = `plate_qualities`.`id` 
 inner join `processes` on `process_id` = `processes`.`id` 
 where project_id IN(SELECT id from projects WHERE name like 'SPIRIT')
 group by equipment_status_codes.name, plate_qualities.name, processes.name ASC with ROLLUP
```

Note: You can use SQL output with `$query->toSql()` and then compare with your actual SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Try following Query for Joining with where Condition

```
return Plate::select('equipment_status_codes.name as Status', 'plate_qualities.name as Quality', 'processes.name as Process')
->join('equipment_status_codes', 'plates.equipment_status_code_id', '=', 'equipment_status_codes.id')
->join('plate_qualities', 'plates.plate_quality_id', '=', 'plate_qualities.id')
->join('processes', function($join)
{
    $join->on('plates.process_id', '=', 'processes.id')
    ->whereIn('project_id', DB::table('projects')->where('name','LIKE','SPIRIT')->select('id')->get()->toArray());
})
->groupBy(DB::raw('equipment_status_code_id WITH ROLLUP'))
->get();
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the table method on the DB facade to begin a query. The table method returns a fluent query builder instance for the given table, allowing you to chain more constraints onto the query and then finally get the results using the get method:

Check its link and get knowladge for laravel query builder:-
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries